# Regex to get "Configuración de clientes" from this HTML

Tags: html, regex

I have this HTML but in my actual regex I can't get only the last ocurrence with the words `"Configuración de clientes"`. How can I do that?

Regex `">(.*?)<\/a>`

```
<p><em class="featured-box-primary fa fa-check"></em><a href="/Administrativo/Generales/Clientes/General">Configuración de clientes</a></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to catch all ocurence of link ?

Comment: I want to catch only the part with "Configuración de clientes" but my regex gets various coincidences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not parse complete html pages via regex - html is more then regex can handle. Use a xml/xhtml-parser instead.

For small snippets regex can work:

The `.` will match `>` as well - thats why your match is that big. Instead you can use

```
">([^>]*?)<\/a>
```

which boils down to

```
"         literal
>         literal
(         start of grouping  
 [^>]*?      as few as possible characters that are not a literal >
)         end of grouping
```